# Android HAL for communicating between different partitions

Tags: android, android-hardware

I know HAL is used for abstracting out hardware implementation and is an interface between android and low level drivers/kernel. I also came to know HAL is sometimes used for communicating between different partitions like from /system to /vendor because of security. Couldnt find any readings for same. Is HAl used for such communication if yes how.